# Java (byte) ((localIntBuffer[srcIdx + col] >> 8) & 0xFF)

Tags: java, delphi

I hate myself to ask this question, but i couldn't find any solution anywhere.

```
(byte) ((localIntBuffer[srcIdx + col] >> 8) & 0xFF)
```

This code writed with Java, and i would like to learn equals in Delphi and what is the meaning of this code?

Comment: Couldn't find anywhere ? What about [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and [`this`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operators) ? It makes me feel you didn't spend more than 20 seconds on your research.

Comment: @TLama sorry you are right, i am a bad searcher :(

Comment: This seems to be getting the second least significant byte out of an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The `>>` operator is signed right shift.
- The `&` operator is bitwise and.
- The `(byte)` is a cast to `byte`.
- The `[]` is the array indexing operator.

In Delphi this would be written like this:

```
(localIntBuffer[srcIdx + col] shr 8) and $ff
```

There's no need for a cast in Delphi because all integral types are assignment compatible and the `and $ff` ensures that the value is in the correct range.

The distinction between signed shift and unsigned shift is not important here because you are picking out bits 8-15 from a 32 bit signed integer. Well, I presume that `localIntBuffer` is an array of `int`. It would have better had you said so rather than leaving us to guess. It is a very common novice mistake to believe that code alone suffices. Invariably knowledge of types is crucial too.

As @TLama correctly points out, it pays to consult the documentation:

- Java operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html
- Delphi operators: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operators

Another way to write this would be to use `LongRec` from `SysUtils` to pick out the desired byte:

```
LongRec(localIntBuffer[srcIdx + col]).Bytes[1]
```